# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: bookmarks_mytag

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: bookmarks_mytag` trying to install a django project.
The repo is at http://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/bookwormbud.git

We did

```
touch db.sqlite3
python manage.py migrate
```

and it blows up:

```
(bookwormbuddy) john@john-Precision-3510:~/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f7adbb5e140>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookwormbud/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^',           include('bookmarks.urls',   namespace='bookmarks')),
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bookmarks import views
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/views.py", line 24, in <module>
    from bookmarks.forms        import ArticleForm, TagForm, TagSelectForm, EditArticleForm, AddedDateCalendarForm, LastViewedDateCalendarForm
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/forms.py", line 120, in <module>
    class TagSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/forms.py", line 127, in TagSelectForm
    choices=get_tag_choices()
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/forms.py", line 112, in get_tag_choices
    if tags:
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __nonzero__
    return type(self).__bool__(self)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 886, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: bookmarks_mytag
^C(bookwormbuddy) john@john-Precision-3510:~/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca$ touch db.sqlite3
(bookwormbuddy) john@john-Precision-3510:~/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookwormbud/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^',           include('bookmarks.urls',   namespace='bookmarks')),
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from bookmarks import views
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/views.py", line 24, in <module>
    from bookmarks.forms        import ArticleForm, TagForm, TagSelectForm, EditArticleForm, AddedDateCalendarForm, LastViewedDateCalendarForm
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/forms.py", line 120, in <module>
    class TagSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/forms.py", line 127, in TagSelectForm
    choices=get_tag_choices()
  File "/home/john/Documents/cody_work/codyc54321-bookwormbud-f7f43c3908ca/bookmarks/forms.py", line 112, in get_tag_choices
    if tags:
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __nonzero__
    return type(self).__bool__(self)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 254, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1118, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/envs/bookwormbuddy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 886, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: bookmarks_mytag
```

The project installs immediately on a different laptop, but I don't remember how it was set up. The sqlite db has been deleted and remade empty as it was said to do on SO. Any help appreciated, thank you

Comment: What if run ```makemigrations``` before that ```migrate```?

Comment: Yes julian, we get the exact same error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: bookmarks_mytag`

Comment: You said sqlite db has been deleted. Did you create the file `db.sqlite3`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an empty db file manually. You dont need to create that file manually. Delete your "db.sqlite3" file, then run command,

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

If above command says "No changes detected", then run this command,

```
python manage.py makemigrations app_name
```

where, app_name will be your directory name in which models.py file is located,

using above command, you have successfully created migration files,
Now, simpy run,

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I hope this help

Comment: This partially helped. In the end I just replaced the sqlite3db with a working one from the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `python manage.py makemigrations` before `migrate`?